# Devise Authentication using cURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl, devise

How can I authenticate my Ruby on Rails Application using cURL from terminal using Devise?

I'm trying:

```
curl --user email:password http://domain.bla/api/auth/sign_in
```

And is responding:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me :

```
curl -XPOST -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://domain/api/v1/auth/sign_in -d '{"email": "email@domain.com", "password": "password" }
```

So I get back the response (something like below, only important part) :

```
< access-token: lW1c60hYkRwAinzUqgLfsQ
< token-type: Bearer
< client: W_xCQuggzNOVeCnNZbjKFw
< expiry: 1426610121
< uid: email@domain.com
```

Then I can validate the token, using the client and token previously obtained from the above request, I do it like this :

```
curl -XGET -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'access-token: lW1c60hYkRwAinzUqgLfsQ' -H 'client: W_xCQuggzNOVeCnNZbjKFw' -H "uid: email@domain.com" http://domain/api/v1/auth/validate_token
```

The result :

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":3,"provider":"email","uid":"email@domain.com","firstname":null,"lastname":null,"email":"email@domain.com"}}
```

Comment: Now can you give me an example for put method ?

Comment: Hey, sorry but it doesn't work for me. I have always a 401 Status Code, why?

Answer (score 7):

I found that the login step needed to be wrapped in a `user` dictionary, viz:

```
curl -X POST -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ 
  http://somehost.com/users/sign_in -d \ 
  '{"user" : {"email": "some_user@nowhereville.org", "password": "OpenSecret" }}'
```

This is Devise 3.5.4.