# Hit web endpoints behind Devise authentication with non-browser request in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, curl, devise

How can I request pages in a Rails app which are behind Devise authentication?

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841168/devise-authentication-using-curl) from 5 years ago suggests hitting `/sign_in` and then using the returned access_token in future requests.

But when I make a request, no `access_token` is returned.

```
curl -XPOST -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"email": "me@app.com", "password": "12345678" }'
```

**Response:**

The response is this, followed by the html for the page that is normally then returned.

```
* upload completely sent off: 56 out of 56 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"2477...80"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 2351...ad
< X-Runtime: 0.785395
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But I have no tokens with which to make further requests.

Is what I'm trying possible with Ruby on Rails in 2020?

Or is there a way to hack devise to make it work?

---

**UPDATE:**

It's the site of my employer. Can't share unfortunately.

They want a way to test that logic behind newly added routes works, without needing to login and click through the UI.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm ok hitting the endpoints with curl, Postman, (anything) etc.

Comment: Devise does not support token based authentication out of the box (it never has). It is session (cookie) based. So your expectation that you can just cURL and get a token it might be completely unrealistic.

Comment: show us a live website using devise. @max its probably cookies combined with CSRF tokens

Comment: What is the use case? That informs the solution. If it's your own app, then ofc add a token auth endpoint to devise (see their docs) or simple basic auth. If it's another site, what you are looking for are scraping techniques. For that you may use capybara and `Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome`

Comment: @oma I added some more context in an "update". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is scraping with capybara. You haven't said why you tried curl, just that 'your employer wants to test logic behind newly added routes'. In that case you want to study response. Capybara is designed for that purpose.

Ofc you should test logic with unit test, but I'm not here to judge the reasoning.

my_scraper.rb

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'webdrivers'

# Google chrome stable must be installed locally:
# https://linuxconfig.org/google-chrome-web-browser-installation-on-debian-9-stretch-linux

class MyScraper
  include Capybara::DSL

  attr_reader :domain, :email, :password
  def initialize(email:, password:, domain: "http://localhost:3000")
    @domain = domain
    @email = email
    @password = password
    register_chrome_driver
    Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
    Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 60
    log_in
  end

  def log_in
    visit "#{domain}/users/sign_in"
    fill_in 'Email', with: email
    fill_in 'Password', with: password
    click_button 'Logg inn'
  end

  def test_urls
    visit "#{domain}/some/url"
    #check results. See the documentation
    visit "#{domain}/some/url2"
    visit "#{domain}/another/path"
    # ...
  end

  # Source: https://gist.github.com/bbonamin/4b01be9ed5dd1bdaf909462ff4fdca95
  def register_chrome_driver
    options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
    end
  end
end
```

run it

```
$ irb
load 'my_scraper.rb'
MyScraper.new(email: "me@app.com", password: "12345678").test_urls
```